# How to set ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable before starting debug environment in VSCode?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, ros

I would like to add `/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS` to the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` variable before the ROS debug session starts. If it isn't added, the debugger won't start, because it cannot find the package.
I would like to export the variable before the ROS debug starts.

##### What I already tried:

###### I tried to add it as an environment variable in the `launch.json` in two different ways:

first way:

```
{
    "name": "ROS: Launch + build (release)",
    "type": "ros",
    "request": "launch",
    "target": "/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3/launch/ORB_SLAM3_bag.launch",
    "env": {"ROS_PACKAGE_PATH": "/opt/ros/melodic/share:/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS"}
}
```

second way:

```
{
    "name": "ROS: Launch + build (release)",
    "type": "ros",
    "request": "launch",
    "target": "/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3/launch/ORB_SLAM3_bag.launch",
    "environment": [{"name": "ROS_PACKAGE_PATH", "value": "/opt/ros/melodic/share:/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS"}]
}
```

###### I tried to add it to an `.env` file, and set the envFile property in `launch.json`:

`.env` file:

```
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/share:/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS
```

`launch.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "ROS: Launch + build (release)",
    "type": "ros",
    "request": "launch",
    "target": "/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3/Examples/ROS/ORB_SLAM3/launch/ORB_SLAM3_bag.launch",
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env"
}
```

###### I tried adding a `prelaunchTask`:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}:/home/sanya/work/ORB_SLAM3_multi/Examples/ROS
```

This option works— the `export` happens (I ran `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` after to check)— but the debug session starts in a different terminal (if I understand correctly) and the variable won't be set to the correct value in the debug session.

The only thing that has worked is adding it to the `.bashrc` file. This isn't really ok for me, because I have a modified version of the same library, and I would like to use them both (I will benchmark the modified version against the original), and I wouldn't like to modify the `.bashrc` file everytime when switching between the 2 versions.

Is there another option to export variables to the VSCode debug environment?

Answer (score 2):

(I maintain the Microsoft VSCode ROS extension.)
The extension inherits most of the environment from the ROS environment it is launched from, so if you need to set environment variables (or relocate ROS), you can set them in a terminal and launch code from the terminal.

I create a feature request - https://github.com/ms-iot/vscode-ros/issues/646, and assigned it to our 0.8.0 which I'm working on now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the work you're doing. The extension is great, and I'm looking forward to 0.8.0!